# How to get this variational auto encoder to use images with different resolution?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to get an existing variational auto encoder to work with RGB images that have a resolution of 254 * 254

The code for the variational auto encoder works great for a dataset with resolutions of 100 x 100. However, I have no idea how to modify it to work with images of 254 X 254.

```py
batch_size = 5
epochs = 10
size = 15
no_cuda = True
seed = 1
log_interval = 50
results_path = 'C:\\results\\'
train_root = 'C:\\train\\'
val_root = 'C:\\train\\'

cuda = not no_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()

torch.manual_seed(seed)

device = torch.device("cuda" if cuda else "cpu")
kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True} if cuda else {}


train_loader_food = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.ImageFolder(train_root, transform=transforms.ToTensor()),
    batch_size = batch_size, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

val_loader_food = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.ImageFolder(val_root, transform=transforms.ToTensor()),
    batch_size = batch_size, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

class VAE_CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VAE_CNN, self).__init__()

        # Encoder
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)

        # Latent vectors mu and sigma
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(25 * 25 * 16, 2048)
        self.fc_bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(2048)
        self.fc21 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc22 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)

        # Sampling vector
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc_bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(2048)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(2048, 25 * 25 * 16)
        self.fc_bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(25 * 25 * 16)

        # Decoder
        self.conv5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv6 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv7 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv8 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def encode(self, x):
        conv1 = self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        conv2 = self.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(conv1)))
        conv3 = self.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(conv2)))
        conv4 = self.relu(self.bn4(self.conv4(conv3))).view(-1, 25 * 25 * 16)

        fc1 = self.relu(self.fc_bn1(self.fc1(conv4)))

        r1 = self.fc21(fc1)
        r2 = self.fc22(fc1)

        return r1, r2

    def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
        if self.training:
            std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
            eps = Variable(std.data.new(std.size()).normal_())
            return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)
        else:
            return mu

    def decode(self, z):
        fc3 = self.relu(self.fc_bn3(self.fc3(z)))
        fc4 = self.relu(self.fc_bn4(self.fc4(fc3))).view(-1, 16, 25, 25)

        conv5 = self.relu(self.bn5(self.conv5(fc4)))
        conv6 = self.relu(self.bn6(self.conv6(conv5)))
        conv7 = self.relu(self.bn7(self.conv7(conv6)))
        return self.conv8(conv7).view(-1, 3, 100, 100)

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(x)
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
        return self.decode(z), mu, logvar

class customLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(customLoss, self).__init__()
        self.mse_loss = nn.MSELoss(reduction="sum")

    def forward(self, x_recon, x, mu, logvar):
        loss_MSE = self.mse_loss(x_recon, x)
        loss_KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())

        return loss_MSE + loss_KLD

model = VAE_CNN().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

loss_mse = customLoss()

val_losses = []
train_losses = []

def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(train_loader_food):
        data = data.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        recon_batch, mu, logvar = model(data)
        loss = loss_mse(recon_batch, data, mu, logvar)
        loss.backward()
        train_loss += loss.item()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % log_interval == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader_food.dataset),
                       100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader_food),
                       loss.item() / len(data)))

    print('====> Epoch: {} Average loss: {:.4f}'.format(
        epoch, train_loss / len(train_loader_food.dataset)))
    train_losses.append(train_loss / len(train_loader_food.dataset))
```

I replaced any refence to 25 * 25 * 16 with 128 * 128 * 4 etc.. assuming that would fix the issue but it just yields the following error:

shape '[-1, 64516]' is invalid for input of size 327680

Answer (score 0):

The `25*25*16` comes from number of output channels of `conv4` which is `16` and 1/4 of original image dimension (`100/4 = 25`).
A more generic model code would be:

```
class VAE_CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, h, w):
        super(VAE_CNN, self).__init__()
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        # Encoder
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)

        # Latent vectors mu and sigma
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(h//4 * w//4 * 16, 2048)
        self.fc_bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(2048)
        self.fc21 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc22 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)

        # Sampling vector
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc_bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(2048)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(2048, h//4 * w//4 * 16)
        self.fc_bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(h//4 * w//4 * 16)

        # Decoder
        self.conv5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv6 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv7 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv8 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def encode(self, x):
        conv1 = self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        conv2 = self.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(conv1)))
        conv3 = self.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(conv2)))
        conv4 = self.relu(self.bn4(self.conv4(conv3)))
        conv4 = conv4.view(-1, self.h//4 * self.w//4 * 16)

        fc1 = self.relu(self.fc_bn1(self.fc1(conv4)))

        r1 = self.fc21(fc1)
        r2 = self.fc22(fc1)

        return r1, r2

    def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
        if self.training:
            std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
            eps = Variable(std.data.new(std.size()).normal_())
            return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)
        else:
            return mu

    def decode(self, z):
        fc3 = self.relu(self.fc_bn3(self.fc3(z)))
        fc4 = self.relu(self.fc_bn4(self.fc4(fc3))).view(-1, 16, self.h//4, self.w//4)

        conv5 = self.relu(self.bn5(self.conv5(fc4)))
        conv6 = self.relu(self.bn6(self.conv6(conv5)))
        conv7 = self.relu(self.bn7(self.conv7(conv6)))
        return self.conv8(conv7).view(-1, 3, self.h, self.w)

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(x)
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
        return self.decode(z), mu, logvar

class customLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(customLoss, self).__init__()
        self.mse_loss = nn.MSELoss(reduction="sum")

    def forward(self, x_recon, x, mu, logvar):
        loss_MSE = self.mse_loss(x_recon, x)
        loss_KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())

        return loss_MSE + loss_KLD

model = VAE_CNN(100, 100).to(device)
```

This would work fine for any image having image dimensions divisible by 4.

Now, as `254%4 != 0`. You can try this one:

```
class VAE_CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, h, w):
        super(VAE_CNN, self).__init__()
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        # Encoder
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)

        # Latent vectors mu and sigma
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(h//2 * w//2 * 16, 2048)
        self.fc_bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(2048)
        self.fc21 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc22 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)

        # Sampling vector
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc_bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(2048)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(2048, h//2 * w//2 * 16)
        self.fc_bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(h//2 * w//2 * 16)

        # Decoder
        self.conv5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.conv6 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.conv7 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv8 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def encode(self, x):
        conv1 = self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        conv2 = self.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(conv1)))
        conv3 = self.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(conv2)))
        conv4 = self.relu(self.bn4(self.conv4(conv3)))
        conv4 = conv4.view(-1, self.h//2 * self.w//2 * 16)

        fc1 = self.relu(self.fc_bn1(self.fc1(conv4)))

        r1 = self.fc21(fc1)
        r2 = self.fc22(fc1)

        return r1, r2

    def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
        if self.training:
            std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
            eps = Variable(std.data.new(std.size()).normal_())
            return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)
        else:
            return mu

    def decode(self, z):
        fc3 = self.relu(self.fc_bn3(self.fc3(z)))
        fc4 = self.relu(self.fc_bn4(self.fc4(fc3))).view(-1, 16, self.h//2, self.w//2)

        conv5 = self.relu(self.bn5(self.conv5(fc4)))
        conv6 = self.relu(self.bn6(self.conv6(conv5)))
        conv7 = self.relu(self.bn7(self.conv7(conv6)))
        return self.conv8(conv7).view(-1, 3, self.h, self.w)

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self.encode(x)
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
        return self.decode(z), mu, logvar

class customLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(customLoss, self).__init__()
        self.mse_loss = nn.MSELoss(reduction="sum")

    def forward(self, x_recon, x, mu, logvar):
        loss_MSE = self.mse_loss(x_recon, x)
        loss_KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())

        return loss_MSE + loss_KLD

model = VAE_CNN(254, 254).to(device)
```